# Selecting rows with datetime in which the full ISO week has passed

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime

I need to select rows from a table which have a datetime within a full ISO week that has passed. The table is a daily transaction table, which I use to aggregate numbers with ISO weeks. If I aggregate the table today this week's aggregation will only be based on transaction data in the current week, which hasn't ended yet. So, as of writing the current year and week is 2019-19. I would like to subtract one week, so that only rows with year and week 2019-18 or earlier are retrieved.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, and am therefore missing the MySQL function YEARWEEK which I believe would make this much easier. Essentially I am trying to do what I believe `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE YEARWEEK(TransactionDateTime) <= YEARWEEK(DATEADD(week, -1, MAX(TransactionDateTime)))` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE YEAR(TransactionDateTime) = 2019
AND  DATEPART(WEEK,TransactionDateTime) = DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()) - 1
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `where` clause is not [SARGable](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/cant-index-probably-not-sargable/).

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani, but I'm not getting the result set needed. I also need data from previous years so I set a variable and adjusted the code:

>`DECLARE @MaxYear int`

>`SET @MaxYear = (SELECT YEAR(MAX(TransactionDateTime)) FROM TableA)`

>`SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE YEAR(TransactionDateTime) <= @MaxYear
AND DATEPART(WEEK, LevDat) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) - 1`

But then I'm just getting data until week 18 for all previous years as well. Also, data for Sundays are missing, so I would need this to work with ISO weeks.

Comment: So for example the week number today is 19. You wants to data for week 18 (Only!!) from all previous year? like 2019,2018,2017...

Comment: ISO Week issue can be solved easily. If you clear me on my earlier comments, I will try to help with the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates how to determine the starting date of an ISO week (Always Monday.) for a two month window of dates. From there it is a simple matter to subtract one week to get the start of the prior ISO week.

```
with
  Dates as (
    -- Sample dates from the start of the current month ...
    select Cast( DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( GetDate() ), GetDate() ) as Date ) as TheDate
    union all
    -- ... through two full months.
    select DateAdd( day, 1, TheDate )
      from Dates
      where TheDate < Cast( DateAdd( month, 2, DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( GetDate() ), GetDate() ) ) as Date )
    ),
  DatesWithISOWeeks as (
    select TheDate, DatePart( iso_week, TheDate ) as ISOWeek,
      -- Calculate the Monday on which the ISO week started regardless of  @@DateFirst   or language settings.
      DateAdd( day, -( ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, TheDate ) - 2 ) % 7 ), TheDate ) as StartOfISOWeek
      from Dates )
  -- Output the results.
  select TheDate, ISOWeek, StartOfISOWeek,
    DateAdd( week, -1, StartOfISOWeek ) as StartOfPriorISOWeek
    from DatesWithISOWeeks;
```

A `where` clause the compares `TransactionDateTime` to boundaries is SARGable, i.e. it can benefit from an index on `TransactionDateTime`:

```
where StartOfPriorISOWeek <= TransactionDateTime and TransactionDateTime < StartOfISOWeek
```

Note that the comparisons are `<=` and `<` so that only one week, not eight days, are included. Since the year is incorporated in the dates no other comparison is needed.

Also note that the calculations are independent of the setting of `@@DateFirst` and the current language:

```
select Cast( DateAdd( day, -( ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, GetDate() ) - 2 ) % 7 ), Getdate() ) as Date ) as StartOfISOWeek;
```